# Additional keyword syntax highlighting (for ReSharper C++)

Tags: c++, resharper, resharper-9.0, resharper-c++

I'm trying to use a new keyword (`await`), but ReSharper C++ marks it in red, and it really stands out and annoying. I've tried to disable the color highlighting, but it still shows up in red.

Completely suspending ReSharper or disabling Code Analysis seems to fix the problem, shifting back to Visual Studio's default syntax highlighting, but then that's the code analysis suggestions is whole reason I purchased ReSharper in the first place! I just want the await to be marked in blue, and code analysis to (sometimes) work.

It seems to be an issue with `await` being recognized as an unresolved symbol and being marked and highlighted with `ReSharper Error Highlighting` rule in Visual Studio's `Environment > Fonts and Colors` options.

My question is, is there any way to fix this problem, maybe by adding a new keyboard, or some macro hacks?

#### ReSharper enabled, "color identifiers" on and off (doesn't matter)

[image]

#### ReSharper disabled

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper does not support such construction https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-15121